# grouping time intervals on Redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to achieve the following:

from a timestamp I would like to indicate where time part falls under which interval like. 08:00:00 - 12:59:59, 13:00:00 - 17:59:59, 18:00:00 - 22:59:59 etc. the whole idea is wrapped around that I want to determine what time on a day a website is mostly visited. I have used `cast(timestamp as time)` it does not work, I have done a `select '2018-05-25 12:00:00'::time` it does extract the time but only when it is typed in text and not a column name, I am hoping to use 'suppose this code was working':

```
select timestamp::time between '08:00:00'::time and '12:59:59'
```

my initial solution was, which my manager says it is wrong.

```
sum(case when cast(substring(split_part(event_date, ' ', 2),1,2) as int) in (23,00,01,02,03,04) then 1 else 0 end) as time_23_04,
sum(case when cast(substring(split_part(event_date, ' ', 2),1,2) as int) between 5 and 7 then 1 else 0 end) as time_05_07,
sum(case when cast(substring(split_part(event_date, ' ', 2),1,2) as int) between 8 and 12 then 1 else 0 end) as time_08_12,
sum(case when cast(substring(split_part(event_date, ' ', 2),1,2) as int) between 13 and 17 then 1 else 0 end) as time_13_17,
sum(case when cast(substring(split_part(event_date, ' ', 2),1,2) as int) between 18 and 22 then 1 else 0 end)  as time_18_22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extract dateparts using EXTRACT()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event_date), 23) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS time_23_04,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event_date) BETWEEN  5 AND  7 THEN 1 END) AS time_05_07,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event_date) BETWEEN  8 AND 12 THEN 1 END) AS time_08_12,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event_date) BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN 1 END) AS time_13_17,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM event_date) BETWEEN 18 AND 22 THEN 1 END) AS time_18_22
FROM table
```

The first line is just my bit of fun. It's the same as your IN statement.

Also, if the `CASE` statement does not find a match, it returns `NULL`, which is ignored by `SUM`.